# Tables don't get aligned using MaterializeCSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, materialize

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row">
        <div class="col m4">
            <table id="tbl_otherProfile">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <h1>Estadísticas</h1>
                        <h2>10912 Letras escritas</h2>
                        <h2>3872 Palabras escritas</h2>
                        <h2>10 Doc. editados</h2>
                        <h2>52 Horas online</h2>
                        <h2>117 Respuestas</h2>
                        <h2>37 Preguntas</h2>
                        <h2>5 Medallas</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col m4">
            <table align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <h1>Enviar</h1>
                        <h1>Mensaje</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="tbl_otherProfile">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <h1>Información Personal</h1>
                        <h2>Alumno de 4 TIC B</h2>
                        <h2>Fecha de nacimiento</h2>
                        <h2>18/10/1992</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col m4">
            <table id="tbl_otherProfile" style="height:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <h1>Medallas</h1>
                        <h2><img src="../../Content/img/firstPlace.png" /> Más palabras escritas de la clase</h2>
                        <h2><img src="../../Content/img/hoursMedal.png" /> 50 horas online</h2>
                        <h2><img src="../../Content/img/certificate.png" /> 100 preguntas respondidas</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

So I have this code and for some reason the tables aren't getting well formatted, tbl_otherProfile has only

```
background-color: #cfd8dc;
border:medium solid #90a4ae;
border-radius:6px;
```

So what I want to do is to align the tables correctly, as you can see in this image:

[image]

the tables aren't getting aligned correctly and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are few things that might be your problem, first, You have not got any **width** or **height** set, try to fix that, second, you should have some **padding**, try to use it. Maybe those are your problems...